# How to create a self-aware prototype?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript we often need to use class-like `function` objects. A class-like `function` object often needs public members instead of parameters, but this seems to be too labor-intensive on the long term:

```
function MyClassLikeFunction(params) {
    this.width = (params.width === undefined) ? 50 : params.width;
    this.height = (params.height === undefined) ? 50 : params.height;
    this.name = (params.name === undefined) ? "foobar" : params.name;
    //And a lot of these initializations and some function definitions
}
```

Instead of this I intend to be able to define things like this:

```
function MyClassLikeFunction(params) {
    //something to enable the behavior
    this.initialize("width", 50);
    this.initialize("height", 50);
    this.initialize("name", "foobar");
    //And a lot of these initializations and some function definitions
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I wonder how did I deserve the down-vote.

Comment: If you're okay with using ES6 code (or a polyfill), you could do `Object.assign(this, defaults, params)`.

Comment: I still wonder about the problem with the question.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work to try to make JS something it isn't really, especially since ES6+ starts to address class-like behavior.

Comment: @DaveNewton, hence the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for this:

```js
function MyConstructor(params) {
    Object.assign(this, {
        // defaults:
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        name: 'foobar'
    }, params);    
}

var obj = new MyConstructor( {width: 100, height: 51} );

console.log(obj);
```

#### Can this be used for private variables?

Yes, like this for example (destructuring assignment):

```
var {height, width, name} = Object.assign({
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    name: 'foobar'
}, params);    

console.log(height);
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. Does it support storing properties in a private manner as well?

Comment: @LajosArpad: There are no private properties in javascript.

Comment: function foo() {var bar = "lorem";} bar is private.

Comment: @LajosArpad: But not a property.

Comment: @Bergi, right, I actually meant private local variables. Sorry for the misunderstandable description.

Comment: @LajosArpad, yes you can use  `Object.assign` for other, private variables. I added a paragraph in my answer for that.

Comment: @trincot, thanks. Also, according to your criticism I have edited my question to improve its quality.

Comment: You're welcome. I have cleaned-up my answer now that you have improved the terminology in your question ;-)

Comment: @trincot, in fact, the purpose of my question was to share an idea and to see whether it can be resolved in a superior manner. Your answer has clearly shown there is a better solution than mine.

Answer (score -1):

Let us consider this prototype:

```
function Initializable(params) {
    this.initialize = function(key, def, private) {
        if (def !== undefined) {
            (!!private ? params : this)[key] = (params[key] !== undefined) ? params[key] : def;
        }
    };
}
```

With this we are able to define public or private members of a prototype. Example:

```
function MyPrototype(params) {
    Initializable.call(this, params);
    this.initialize("width", 50);
    this.initialize("height", 50);
    this.initialize("name", "foobar");
    //And a lot of these initializations and some function definitions
}
```

Comment: Can someone tell me what the problem is with this answer?

Comment: What is `private` supposed to do?

Comment: @Bergi, private decides whether we include the member into params or this. If it is inside params, then it will be unreachable outside the scope of prototype. Otherwise it will be added to this and will be readable from anywhere the object is reachable.

Comment: Ah, you add the default values to `params`. That's a bit weird though, and in general modifying your arguments is an antipattern.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, it works like that. The reason to add elements to patterns was to not create and maintain a separate variable for that purpose.